# Integration testing for methods annotated with CircuitBreaker not working

Tags: spring, aop, spring-boot-test, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I have a SpringBoot application which has circuitBreaker implemented with annotations. The annotated circuitbreaker is an Aspect so that the client doesnt have to explicitly annotate their methods with the circuitBreaker annotation.When I hit the RequestMapping from the browser in high frequency the circuitbreaker settings are getting applied and the fallback is getting called.

Issue is when I try to test this from the Test class by calling the api using concurrent threads. As the api is down the fallback mechanism kicks in but the config settings of the circuit breaker doesnt come into picture. Also same is the behavior when multiple requests are called from Postman.

Comment: CircuitBreaker is implemented in the client application using Spring AOP so that all the methods that satisfy the pointcut (for example all @RequestMappings in controller) will have CircuitBreaker applied.

Comment: Can you add the relevant application code for this CircuitBreaker usage and the test you currently have in place?